# Collapse and count the number of unique value

Tags: r, date, session, unique-values

I am currently working on an application where I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Database
UserId         Hour         Date
01                18           01.01.2016
01                18           01.01.2016
01                14           02.01.2016
01                14           02.01.2016
02                21           02.01.2016
02                08           05.01.2016
02                08           05.01.2016
03                23           05.01.2016
```

Each line represents a session.

I need to determine whether the time of the first session of a user has an impact on the number of sessions this user is going to have.

I have tried the command `summaryBy`:

```
library(doBy)
first_hour <- summaryBy(UserId + Hour + Date ~ UserId, 
    FUN=c(head, length, unique), database)
```

But it doesn't give me the correct result.

My goal here is to determine the `Hour` of the first session a user takes, determine how many sessions and how many different session dates a user has.

Comment: Please show the expected output.  Perhaps `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, .N ,names(df1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'UserId', we `order` the 'Date', get the `first` 'Hour', total number of sessions (`.N`) and the number of `unique` Date elements (`uniqueN(Date)`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(UserId, as.Date(Date, "%m.%d.%Y")),.(Hour = Hour[1L],
      Sessions = .N, DifferSessionDate = uniqueN(Date)) , by = UserId]
#    UserId Hour Sessions DifferSessionDate
#1:      1   18        4                 2
#2:      2   21        3                 2
#3:      3   23        1                 1
```

Comment: Thank you although it should give me the hour of the first session, in this case for example UserId#1 have its first session at 18 and not at 14

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(UserId) %>% summarise(FirstHour = min(Hour),
                                      NumSessions = n(),
                                      NumDates = length(unique(Date)))

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

  UserId FirstHour NumSessions NumDates
   (int)     (int)       (int)    (int)
1      1        14           4        2
2      2         8           3        2
3      3        23           1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base` commands, you can write your own function to select desired information:

```
user.info <- function(user){
    temp <- subset(Database, Database$UserId == user)
    return(c(UserId=user, FirstHour=temp$Hour[1], Sessions=nrow(temp), Dates=length(unique(temp$Date))))
}

t(sapply(unique(Database$UserId), FUN=user.info)) 
#     UserId FirstHour Sessions Dates
# [1,]      1        18        4     2
# [2,]      2        21        3     2
# [3,]      3        23        1     1
```

Here, `FirstHour` is the hour on the first listed row for the given user, `Sessions` is the number of rows for the user and `Dates` is the number of different dates listed for the user.

The function is applied to all unique users and the final table is transposed.